# Torque on a current loop due to uniform magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, torque

I know that torque on a current carrying coil is = M x B. But my doubt is from which point is this torque defined? I have seen in many questions that this equation of torque is used from any point we want, but is it right? since torque on a body depends on the point of reference

Comment: I know it works with the point of reference in the center of a rectangular loop, so you might have trouble when you use this formula in other cases. Personally I wouldn't use this formula in more difficult situations.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is good as applied to any reference point. $\bf M$ is not a fixed value independent of reference point. It depends on the reference point.

Comment: How can M(magnetic moment) depend on reference point? Isn't it simply = (current)(area)

Comment: The definition of the magnetic moment of a current distribution is ${\bf M} = \frac{1}{2} \int_V {\bf x}' \times{\bf J({\bf x}' )} d^3x'$ and this quantity clearly depends on the choice of origin (reference point).

Answer (score 0):

If the magnet field is uniform then the net force on the current carrying loop due to magnetic field will be zero. When a body is in equilibrium (no net force on it) and is rotating about an axis then the net torque on the body is independent of the choice of origin. It can be very easily proved using vector algebra.